# How can I get project facets and deployment assembly configured in Eclipse Kepler through m2e

Tags: m2e

I'm quite new in Maven and m2e. I tried to drop .classpath and .settings from my git repo.

I do maven update after I checkout my projects on a new workspace. However, I always need to manually set the project facets (Java & utility for my case) in order to get the path mappings right in deployment in assembly. Can someone tell me if it's possible to have m2e derive them from the pom?

Thanks!